# Mysql configuration file permission problem

Tags: mysql, permissions, config, my.cnf

in etc/mysql/my.cnf my.cnf is blocked in 777 permission and when I change it to any other permission it will stay at 777 and will not change.
the only content of my.cnf is:

```
!includedir /etc/mysql/conf.d/
!includedir /etc/mysql/mysql.conf.d/
```

Same for mysqld.cnf in etc/mysql/mysql.conf.d/mysqld.cnf any permission that I give to mysqld.cnf other than 777 will make that MySQL failed to restart.

And I got this error: mysql warning world writable config file etc/mysql/mysql.conf.d/mysqld.cnf is ignored

What I understand is that any config in mysqld.cnf will be ignored because it's 777 but if I change its permission to any other one MySQL will stops.

What should I do to modify the permission of those 2 files without MySQL stops working.

ps: MySQL error.log and mysql.log are empty and never get anything on them, I think it's normal because they're enabled in MySQL config file but this file is ignored because it has permission set to 777.

Comment: What OS/Distro/Version? What filesystem are these files on? How is it mounted? How are you changing the permission?

Comment: I use ubuntu 18.4, I just upgraded MySQL to the latest version and the problem happen

Comment: You've answered one question out of 4 (btw don't drop `0` from versions). That isn't sufficient. They where asked because the answers where needed to understand what could be wrong. If you have trouble answering these ask further and guidance can be given (like look at `mount` output).

Comment: Yes sorry I'mnewbie so I dont know how to answer them all. 
What OS/Distro/Version? ubuntu 18.4
What filesystem are these files on? I don't know how to answer I need guidance
How is it mounted? same
How are you changing the permission? I change them with chmod command on putty or using webmin, right click and change the permission. But for mysql I didn't change any permission manually, I just upgrade it to the latest version and the problem happen